# Why does this SQL Server CE date criterion fail?

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

The filter clause is:

```
AND (TIMESTAMP >= TIMESTAMP) AND (TIMESTAMP <= 2019-09-17)
```

All other clauses pass, and all my dates are 2014-07-31, just the times vary. If I remove the max date constraint, I get a cool 39k records.

BTW, the reason for `(TIMESTAMP >= TIMESTAMP)` is the passed in start time is null, so I always substitute null values with the actual DB values, because they mostly always match.

Comment: Please provide more context - is this the raw sql statement or what. Have you tried "between" ?

Comment: Did you try putting your date string in string delimiters, e.g. `<= '2019-09-17'`? Currently you are saying "less than or equal to (2019 minus 9 minus 17)", which is some date in June of 1905 (number of days from 1900-01-01). And no, [please don't use BETWEEN](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx), even if you really meant `<=` as opposed to `<`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, a favourite habit of mine is, say someone says last year is 1995, they normally mean all of '95, so I add one year, subtract to that years end, and use <, rather than <=.

Comment: @ProfK that's great. You still need to put `'string delimiters'` around `'your date literal'` otherwise it will be treated as a mathematical expression.